# Why I can't open text files when execetue "x" permission is on?

Tags: permissions, gui, chmod, executable, nano

for example I have ***test_file*** and I run `sudo chmod 775 test_file` so now while I'm the owner I can read,write and execute it but with graphical interface it doesn't work, I don't have any error messages it is just doing nothing. I can read it only in terminal using **cat** or edit with for example **nano**. By default text files don't have execute permissions set.

Comment: are you double-clicking on it?  the default action for most file browsers when you double-click on an executable file is to execute it.   Try the right-click menu to view/edit it.  Or, here's a radical and surprising idea: don't make it executable if it's not a script.

Comment: There is no need to use `sudo` to `chmod` a file if you are the owner of said file.

Comment: it opens only when I right click on it and then open with other application and then text editor, so it is the same as double click but it opens the file

Comment: Seems like the graphical interface has some other program configured as the default program to use with text files, and that program is not installed or is failing for some reason. So the double-click (=open with default application) is failing, but right-click and “open with other application” works. To fix it, you could configure the “text editor” to be the default action for text files.

Comment: I checked it and it is a default tool for text files